# Hard to click on links for featured meta posts

Tags: bug, design, meta

I often find it extremely difficult to open a featured meta post:

[image: Featured on meta.Programmers]

Take for example the "Why are we getting so many off topic ..." link. That one spans multiple lines. So I moused over and clicked. But nothing happened.

[image: Can't click...]

Turns out I managed to put my cursor directly over the gap (the gap is one pixel high on my computer).

---

This happens quite frequently for me. It's frustrating because it *always* takes me a few seconds before I realize why the link isn't opening. It feels as if clicking *anywhere* inside the bounds of the link *should* follow the link, but that's not the case.

Comment: Just a wee bit too much line height, heh.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this on Firefox. However, I was able to duplicate on Chrome. On Chrome, changing the `line-height` had no effect on this issue. It appears that Chrome intentionally leaves a single pixel between the lines which is not considered part of the `<a>`.

Comment: @Makyen Interesting. I get the behavior both on Chrome on Windows, and on Firefox on Ubuntu

Comment: The testing I did was on Win10 in both Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tried other browsers.

Comment: Putting a bounty on a request where you want an official response is a rather wasteful use of rep. For better ways to get official attention for feature requests and bug reports, see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in Edge, by the way.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769485/non-clickable-areas-in-multi-line-htmlanchors. Also, putting the <div class="bulletin-item-content"> inside the <a> fixes it.